# Is it possible to start the entire code from the left side of the margin so that it fits in my page?

Tags: equations, margins, alignment

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    \det\begin{pmatrix}
x^3-x^2+5x-9 && 3x^2+20\sqrt{x}+2e^x\\
    x^8+3x^5-6x^3+9&& e^x+\sin x+\cosh x+\tanh x
    \end{pmatrix}
    \\
    =\hfill\frac{f(p,q,x)}{x-2p^2q+p^x+q}
        \end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The problem in my code is the second line is starting from the middle of the page.
I dont know why. I want to align all the lines to the left margin of the margin.

Is there any way to align all the lines to the left.

Here is the screenshot of the file produced(PDF).[image]

Please help

Comment: equations are centred by default, you can make them left aligned by adding `fleqn` to the `\documentclass` options, but that does not change the space available.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle; is there any way I can make the equations look better? Please share the code

Comment: In my textbooks everything is aligned to the left but why cant I do the same in my case?

Comment: *Why* did the code suddenly change to a completely different and meaningless display?

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multline}
    \det\begin{pmatrix}
x^3-x^2+5x-9 && 3x^2+20\sqrt{x}+2e^x\\
    x^8+3x^5-6x^3+9&& e^x+\sin x+\cosh x+\tanh x
    \end{pmatrix}\\
    =\frac{f(p,q,x)}{x-2p^2q+p^x+q}
    \end{multline}
\end{document}
```

but if you want it left aligned

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
     \begin{aligned}
    &\det\begin{pmatrix}
x^3-x^2+5x-9 && 3x^2+20\sqrt{x}+2e^x\\
    x^8+3x^5-6x^3+9&& e^x+\sin x+\cosh x+\tanh x
    \end{pmatrix}\\
    &=\frac{f(p,q,x)}{x-2p^2q+p^x+q}
   \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Its not working Sir

Comment: I already have a document class defined as I need to use a document class provided by the journal to which I am submitting my paper

Comment: I am getting an error code that "Two document classes" cant be defined

Comment: @Math_Freak you can't get that error from the code posted here, you must have two `\documentclass` surely? This code doesn't depend on `article` class, I just used it as you had used it, any class should work.

Answer (score 1):

`split` builds two columns, one right aligned and one left aligned.

Looking at the monster, I think it's better to have the number at the bottom, to remove the intercolumn space from the top matrix to make it fit in the text width
and to do the rest in a separate `equation` environment, with a nested `aligned`.

Avoid the unadorned `\bigg`, look at the code to see what's needed (`l` for left, `r` for right).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\det\begin{pmatrix}
x-pq-p+3-(q-1)\bigl(\frac{x+2-n}{x-n+2-l}\bigr) & (1-p)\bigl(2+\frac{l}{x-n+2-l}\bigr)\\[1ex]
(1-q)\bigl(2+\frac{l}{x-n+2-l}\bigr) & x-pq-q+3-(p-1)\bigl(\frac{x+2-n}{x-n+2-l}\bigr)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Applying the row operation $R_1\gets R_1-R_2$ on the above we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
&=\det\begin{pmatrix}
x-pq-p+q+2 & -x+pq+q-p-2\\[1ex]
(1-q)\bigl(2+\frac{l}{x-n+2-l}\bigr) & x-pq-q+3-(p-1)\bigl(\frac{x+2-n}{x-n+2-l}\bigr)
\end{pmatrix}
\\[2ex]
&=\biggl(x-pq-p+q+2\biggr)\biggl\{x-pq-q+3-(p-1)\biggl(\frac{x+2-n}{x-n+2-l}\biggr)\biggr\}
\\
&\qquad-\biggl\{(-x+pq+q-p-2)(1-q)\biggl(2+\frac{l}{x-n+2-l}\biggr)\biggr\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]